# Using Generics or Templates in c# to simplify object retrieval in my application

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I have a database that has multiple tables that are objects in my application, Member, Employer, Invoice etc.

I want to create a generic method that will allow me to retrieve a single object from any of the tables. ex. public Object GetRow(ClassType type, ClassKey key, object valueToFind)

so the Member method right now would be

```
Member member = _manager.Members.Where(m => m.MemberKey == valueToFind).FirstOrDefauilt();

Employer employer = _manager.Employers.Where(e => e.EmployerKey == valueToFind).FirstOrDefault();

Invoice invoice = _manager.Invoices.Where(i => i.InvoiceKey == valueToFind).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do i write a generic method that would handle all 3 cases?

Comment: Have you tried looking into  building expression trees using lambda expressions?

Comment: What is "_manager" ? Is it EF context ?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius a "meta" lambda expressions would certainly work here. What's amusing is there already are 3 lambdas in his code.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using entity framework. In such case you can write a method like:

```
public T RetrieveFirst<T>( Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
   return _manager.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(filter);
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
var member = RetrieveFirst<Member>(m => m. MemberKey = valueToFind );
```

If you wanted to unify the filtering, the entities would all have to implement an interface and have the same name of the key property.

I think @ajawad987 has written the perfect answer for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement an interface that all your entities (employee, manager, etc.) inherit and then implement a generic method that works with that interface.

Basically you define a simple interface that defines the common `Key` property:

```
public interface IHasKeyProperty
{
  int Key { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : IHasKeyProperty
{
  public int Key { get; set; }

  // Rest of manager code...
}

public class Employee : IHasKeyProperty
{
  public int Key { get; set; }

  // Rest of employee code...
}
```

And then you can write a generic query like this:

```
public TEntity GetByKey<TEntity>(int key)
  where TEntity : IHasKeyProperty, class
{
  return this._dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
}
```

I'm assuming you're using Entity Framework Core, hence the `_dbContext` variable in my snippet above.

Using the method would look like this:

```
var myEmployee = GetByKey<Employee>(207);
var myManager = GetByKey<Manager>(101);
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend @ajawad987's answer, if you need to support different key types you could do:

```
   public interface IHasKeyProperty<TId>
        {
            TId Key { get; set; }
        }

        public class Manager : IHasKeyProperty<int>
        {
            public int Key { get; set; }

            // Rest of manager code...
        }

        public class Employee : IHasKeyProperty<Guid>
        {
            public Guid Key { get; set; }

            // Rest of employee code...
        }

        public TEntity GetByKey<TEntity, TId>(TId key) where TEntity : IHasKeyProperty<TId>
        {
            return this._dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == key);
        }
```